# What does “white spade” mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, slang, lyrics, cultural-phrases

This is a lyric in the Tom Waits song Heart Attack and Vine - “white spades hanging on a telephone wire”. Does anyone know what this means? I found online that “white spade” refers to an old type of smoking pipe (by the brand Dr. Grabow). I also know that “spade” has been used as an offensive term for Black people in the United States, and found a source that said that Rod Stewart has specifically called himself a “white spade” because of his use of Black American music styles.* Do you think this line has race-related undertones / explicit meaning, or that it is referring to smoking pipes, or something else? The song contains multiple references to drugs and alcohol and although it contains multiple references to sociological phenomena with socioeconomic class-related themes, there would be nothing else explicitly about race, as far as I can tell. Thank you!

*source: https://books.google.com/books?id=LoV6DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT662&lpg=PT662&dq=%22white+spade#v=onepage&q=%22white%20spade&f=false

Comment: ["hanging on the telephone"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging_on_the_Telephone) means waiting on the phone to ring or be answered. So it might refer to someone doing that, rather than an object literally dangling. It might refer to gamblers betting by phone, or not. As for white spades, your guess is better than mine.

Comment: I don't have time to source this all, but my take is that white spades are a kind of shoe, and shoes hanging from a telephone line or power line are supposedly either a memorial to someone who OD'd, or a sign of drug-dealing nearby.  The former seems more likely given the rest of the song but either one could fit.

Comment: Yes, a shoe with a [triangular sole](https://theelegantoxford.com/blogs/news/adding-spade-sole-allen-edmonds-strands)

Comment: Thank you both! I searched for it a bit too and this makes total sense!

Comment: Note, the next word after the quote is "gamblers," so there's perhaps some intentional association simply with the card suit.

Comment: Also, apparently *White Spades* [was the original working title](https://www.thecrimson.com/article/1980/9/18/the-tom-waits-cross-country-marathon-interview/) of the album.

Comment: It's Tom. He'd have had at least two of those meanings in mind.